# JBoss fuse 6.2 takes forever to download maven artifact

Tags: jboss, jbossfuse

I have installed JBoss Fuse 6.2 on CentOs 7. I have set "org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.repositories" in PID "io.fabric8.agent.properties" to also lookup a local repository where my non-snapshot artifacts are. Upon releasing a new version of these artifacts and migrating the container to a higher version, it takes about 1 hour to resolve 10 artifacts. Fuse has access to the internet and can reach every maven repository defined in "io.fabric8.agent.properties". Also the firewall is disabled. What could the problem be? Why does it take this long?

Kind regards,

R.

Comment: Maybe its just a typo but the PID you should be configuring is "io.fabric8.agent" without the "properties" part, that is just the extension of the file.

Comment: That is the PID I am modifying (also clue that it already exists and I am not creating a new PID). Besides it does resolve my artefacts eventually from my custom maven repo. It's just very slow

Answer (score 1):

Just try and add your localrepo at the top in the mvn.repositories , I guess the order of crawl is the order of mention of the repositories , i have seen it happen a few times. I think this change in order should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Sundar. I will give it a go soon and get back to you. Any idea why this is not happening with resolving snapshots from .m2? Could it be because .m2 gets looked up first?

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work Sundar. Any other suggestion that comes to your mind?